# Imagem do botão Close no dialog jQuery não aparece

Tags: jquery-ui

Criei uma janela modal, a janela está funcionando, o botão no canto direito aparece, o evento para fechar a janela funciona perfeitamente, a imagem sobre o botão não aparece.
O que devo fazer?

```
function MessageBox(titulo, mensagem) {

    $('body').append('<div id="janelaMensagem" title="' + titulo + '" style="display:none"> <p>' + mensagem + '</p> </div>');

    $(function () {
        $("#janelaMensagem").dialog({
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            buttons: {
                "Fechar": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            }
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Edite sua pergunta e adicionei mais informações, como partes de código que reproduzam seu problema. Além disto, dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e também a ajuda para [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Do jeito que está é difícil adivinhar o que pode estar ocasionando o problema.

Comment: pode ser algum problema no seu tema do ui.. de um olhada no seu código aqui http://jsfiddle.net/toLxx4fo/ com esse tema https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css :)